# Get Username from computer name using powershell and sccm

Tags: powershell, sccm

I'm attempting to do the following :

Query SCCM using Powershell for a computer name, then, within the output of that, get the UserName.

Right now, I am using :

`Get-CMDevice -name <computername>`

This returns the entire record.  Within that is an item called "UserName".  That's what I want to extract out.

It's been a very long time since working with powershell, let alone the SCCM plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use the member reference operator (`.`):

```
(Get-CMDevice -Name AComputerName).UserName
```

or use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty`:

```
Get-CMDevice -Name AComputerName |Select-Object -ExpandProperty UserName
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to put the command in brackets and select the property directly as shown below:

```
(Get-CMDevice -name <computername>).UserName
```